# Latex equation reference not working as expected

Tags: latex, equation, ref, pdflatex

I am preparing a report and found out `\label` and `\eqref` are not working for equations properly. `\eqref` giving a random equation number and not the exact equation number in the report. I have used `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` numbering for equations, which  means if the equation is in section 5, it will have number from 5.1, 5.2 and so on. But in `\eqref` only 5 is coming and not the exact number of the equation. Is there any solution for this?

```
Equation number \eqref{eq:1}.
\begin{fleqn}[150pt] \label{eq:1}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Delta l^e = u^e_2 - u^e_1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
```

Comment: @whoever voted to migrate to tex.se: Please don't migrate low quality posts. This question does not even mention that the OP uses the nccmath package, see the discussion below the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your label needs to be inside the equation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

Equation number \eqref{eq:1}.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Delta l^e = u^e_2 - u^e_1
\end{aligned}
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you really must use the nccmath package, you could roll back to an older latex version:

```
\RequirePackage[2019/01/01]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{nccmath} 
\numberwithin{equation}{section} 
\begin{document} 
\section{title}
Equation number \eqref{eq:1}. 
\begin{fleqn}[150pt] 
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned} 
\Delta l^e = u^e_2 - u^e_1 
\end{aligned} 
\label{eq:1} 
\end{equation} 
\end{fleqn} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is working for me now. But not working under fleqn environment!%\begin{fleqn}[150pt]
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Delta l^e = u^e_2 - u^e_1
\end{aligned}
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
%\end{fleqn}

Comment: @AjithMS Please add a [mre] to your question which shows where this environment comes from.

Comment: Please see the example.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

Equation number \eqref{eq:1}.
\begin{fleqn}[150pt]
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Delta l^e = u^e_2 - u^e_1
\end{aligned}
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}

Comment: @AjithMS What's your motivation behind using the `fleqn` environment?

Comment: Aligning equations in to the position I want to.